# Showing that the sum of zero-mean noise is zero. Then computing the convolution of zero-mean noise with a given function

Tags: noise, stochastic

This is likely to be a quick fix for people with experience in stochastic processes.

Let $ \eta[k] $ be a sequence of Uniform noise, $ \eta \sim U([-M,M]) $. I want to test if the following is correct theoretically
\begin{equation*} 
\exists B>0\ s.t. \left|\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \eta[k] \right| < B. 
\end{equation*}

In the general case, I would also want to try to test if
\begin{equation*} 
\exists B>0\ s.t. \left|\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \eta[k] \psi [n-k] \right| <B,
\end{equation*}

**What I tried:**

Clearly, for $\psi[k]=1$ the two equations above are equal.

For the first one, I tried using ergodicity, which leads to $$ \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{2N}\sum_{k=-(N-1)}^{N} \eta[k] =0,$$ but this does not imply $$ \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \eta[k] =0.$$

For the second one, it's easy to show that $$\left|\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \eta[k] \psi [n-k] \right|<M\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left| \psi [n-k] \right|, $$ but I don't want to assume that $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \left| \psi [n-k] \right|<\infty.$$

Even if the reader might not have an answer, it would be very helpful to know if this is a trivial result in random processes I am not aware of, or if it is a more complex problem. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!   I think you will need to take the expectation on your first equation.  Otherwise, that summation of just the random uniformly distributed values will never be identically zero (well, it'll have a vanishingly small probability of being zero).  To make the question more sensible, I believe you'll need to put the expectation operator around the summation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Peter! For me expectation would not be useful, because I want to show it is smaller than something in absolutely all cases. I updated saying I want to make it smaller than B in absolute value.

Comment: My intuition is that even though a finite sequence of noise can take any values, when you take an infinite sequence it needs to behave somehow like the pdf, taking both positive and negative values. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Dorian what do you mean by $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} n[k]$? Does it equal to $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{k = -N + 1}^{+N} n[k]$?

Comment: @AlexTP Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Dorian OK, that makes more sense. Thanks for the update. Let me ponder a bit.

Comment: I really recommend that you not use $n$ for both your sequence and as an iterator.  With the proper notation, this should be true:
$$ 
\left|\sum n[k] \psi [n-k] \right| \le \sqrt{\sum n^2[k] } \sqrt{\sum \psi^2 [n-k] }
$$
It's just a dot product after all.  Equality being reached when the two vectors are collinear.

Comment: Also, if I am reading your notation right, there is no need to specify that $B>0$ when you are already specifying it is greater than an absolute value.  I don't believe what you are trying to show is correct.  Going to infinity can be a tricky process, which is why a strict limit approach is needed to do it properly.  I don't see anything that would prove that B is a finite bound.

Comment: @CedronDawg Thanks a lot for the hint, I changed the notation of the noise sequence to $\eta$.

Comment: @CedronDawg Using Cauchy-Schwarz is handy indeed. However, now we would need to show that $$\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z} } \eta^2 [k] <\infty $$, otherwise the bound cannot be used directly. The main challenge here for me is for infinite sequences.

Comment: @CedronDawg Regarding B, my statement was more like $ \exists B>0, s.t. |...|<B$.

Comment: Unfortunately, $<x,y>$ is often used as notation for an inner product, so you can see why the way you expressed can be a a bit confusing.  Again, it's been more than thirty years since my Real Analysis classes, but I am pretty sure you won't get below $ B \cdot N$.  The key is, you have to express all your equations in limit form, do your evaluations, then take the limit.  (Like ATP's comment).  From your premises, I don't see anything that prevents your function (in reverse) to be collinear with your random sequence, thus the equality is a possibility and represents your actual bound.

Comment: The $B>0$ is still redundant and unnecessary.  $\exists B, s.t. |...|<B$ immediately implies $B>0$.  I do think you should edit the question to improve the clarity a bit.  I'm not imperialistic enough to do it myself.

Comment: @CedronDawg Thanks for the comment, I would gladly change it, but this is very common for logical statements in mathematics. Just an extract for the definition of continuous functions on wikipedia (you will find it the same anywhere else) 

"for every $\varepsilon >0 $ there exists a $ \delta >0 $ such that for all $x ∈ D : |x-x_{0}|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_{0})|<\varepsilon $"

It's mainly because after existence you need to specify the set. You could say $ \mathbb{R} $, but it is customary to give the smallest possible set to facilitate its finding.

Comment: @CedronDawg I agree with you, for an arbitrary $ \psi $ the $B\cdot N$ bound can be reached so the sequence could be divergent. So I am going to use the fact that $ \psi $ has a finite support to give a bound for $ N $. Thanks!

Comment: Very good.  FYI, "for every" is quite different than "there exists".  So in your statement, specifying if for $\epsilon$ is appropriate, the $\delta$ specification is redundant.  Whether it is good practice to state both, gosh, I don't remember.

Comment: As an afterthought, I don't think that even the condition that $\psi$ approaches zero as the domain goes to positive or negative infinity is strong enough to give you an overall finite bound.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly: No such $B$ exists. You could simply have a sufficient streak of "bad luck" and draw positive $\eta>\epsilon>0$ continuously, for example. Obviously, $B<\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=-N}^{N-1}\epsilon_n<\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\lvert\sum_{n=-N}^{N-1}\eta_n\right\rvert\,\forall B\in \mathbb R$.

Granted, the event that every $\eta_n>0$ has probability 0 ($=\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=-N}^{N-1} P(\eta_n>0)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\frac12\right)^N$). But you asked for the existence of such $B$, not for a proof of you being able to be sure that you'll be able to pick a finite $B$ which your sum-absolute never exceeds.

Sadly, there exist uncountably infinitely many cases for which the $B$ can't exist, and all have probability 0. Whether or not that makes a non-zero sum probability isn't trivial to say, far as I can tell.

What you could show is that there's a 100% probability that your sum is below some $B$; i.e. show that:
\begin{align}
1&=P\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\lvert\sum_{n=-N}^{N-1}\eta_n\right\rvert<B\right)\\
&=P\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\lvert\underbrace{\sum_{n=-N}^{N-1}\frac{\eta_n}{2N}}_{=:X_N\sim\mathcal N(0,\sigma_\eta^2)}\right\rvert<\frac{B}{2N} \right)\\
&=P\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\left\lvert X_N \right\rvert<\frac{B}{2N} \right)\\
&=P\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}X_N <\frac{B}{2N} \right)-P\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}X_N <-\frac{B}{2N} \right)\\
&=F_{\mathcal N(0,\sigma_\eta^2)}\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{B}{2N}\right) - F_{\mathcal N(0,\sigma_\eta^2)}\left(\lim_{N\to\infty}-\frac{B}{2N}\right)\\
&=\frac12-\frac12\\
&=0\text,
\end{align}

which really isn't a probability of 1. Quite the opposite is true: You can be *certain* that if you let a random walk go on for infinity, that you're infinitely far from where you started.

By the way, the above proof doesn't use the fact that $\eta$ is uniform – it just "needs" that all $\eta_n$ are i.i.d. and that they have bounded variance.

You could construct the very same proof even without knowledge of the central limit theorem, just using Chebyshev's inequality.